# What would be the ending of Matt Kowalski's Mardi Gras story if debris from the missile strike did not interfere with their work?

Tags: gravity-movie

In the movie Gravity, Matt Kowalski was elaborating his "bad feelings" about the mission to Mission Control.

> "Then all of a sudden, I look up and there she is and I'm about to yell out and I see she's holding hands with some short hairy guy in board shorts and a Margaritaville shirt. And then I realized that this guy is not a guy. That my girl is holding hands with..."

Before he could finish the story, he was interrupted by Mission Control, instructing them to disconnect from the Hubble and begin re-entry procedure.

Now, assuming if the debris from the Russian missile strike did not interfere with their work, what would the ending of Matt Kowalski's Mardi Gras story?

Comment: A monkey, obviously.

Comment: A damn dirty ape? Sweet zombie Jesus, *Gravity* was set in orbit of that horrible Planet of the Apes?